# How to exactly located where the program crashes

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, crash

I successfully built a program, and can run it for a while. Then it always crash at some point. I am pretty new to programming, and the only tool I know in Visual Studio is to use Call Stack to trace which functions are called. But still, I cannot determine which functions really caused the problem since I did not see any exception or thrown assertions. Any suggestions on possible solutions or guidance to related tutorials will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: ever heard of debugging?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sc65sadd.aspx

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "crash"? As a user, anything that stops working is "crashed". But as a programmer you'll need to learn to be more precise. It's not a skill easily mastered (experts can do amazing things with limited information) but picking up the basics will be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the debug tool?

left click on the left side of your code(to the left of line number). A red dot should pop up. Then hit play (with debug option), and you can see what your program does step by step.

It will output an error code when it fails. Find out what it means.

Debugging is a great tool, you can see exactly your program goes step by step and see where it crashes.

This may be basic as well, but I would suggest adding cout statements progressively to your code to see where it fails.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you'll need to learn is that a crash has a cause, and a point where it shows up. Those are usually not the same. For instance, if you dereference a null pointer, you'll probably get a crash (certainly in Visual Studio). But the cause is usually earlier, where you should have checked.

A similar type of crash can happen if you dereference a pointer that has been deleted - similar but not identical. Visual Studio will give you an Access Violation in both cases (C0000005) but the pointer at fault is different. Here no check would have helped. Smart pointers would have helped.

A powerful tool is to design your classes with a class invariant. This is a property of an object which is *always* true. For instance, in a String class, an invariant will be that the Size property equals the number of characters in the string. For a double linked list, the forward and back pointers are consistent. Typically this invariant covers `private` data, and all class methods keep the invariant OK. Since other code can't access private methods, they can't break the invariant.

If you add a (debug) function which checks this invariant, you can check in a crash which objects are still valid. Often there's just one broken object. and you then know the bug must be in a bit of code that can change the `private` data.